# /dev/simfs: No such file or directory while opening filesystem

Tags: filesystems, vps, rm

I accidentally removed a wrong folder using rm -rf, every tool I've tried tell me either I have no hard disk or that the filesystem is not found.
When I type df I get :

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/simfs       25G  7.6G   18G  31% /

none            256M   12K  256M   1% /dev

But if I type debugfs -w /dev/simfs I get the error :

```
/dev/simfs: No such file or directory while opening filesystem
```

I'm using a VPS hosted by OVH, what's wrong with that filesystem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scenario/issue. To take the conversation a step further, I've also tried

```
tune2fs -l /dev/simfs
```

which outputs

```
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
tune2fs: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/simfs
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

You'll get the same invalid superblock error if you try to scan an entire disk eg /dev/sda